# TMG Array + Network Load Balancing

Tags: nlb, microsoft-forefront-2010

I have a pretty simple TMG array setup that is managed by an EMS server.

The 2 servers that is in the array TMG01 and TMG02 sits in my DMZ and talks to the EMS server that is on my internal network. After enabling NLB using the EMS server, my TMG01 server keeps dropping off the array. When I go into System on the EMS server TMG02 comes up with a green tick but TMG01 does not.

If I go into services on the TMG01 box I get a "failed to configure network load balancing to work with forefront tmg" error. There is also a couple of random "Forefront TMG detected Windows Filtering Platform filters that may cause policy conflicts on the server".

Any idea what might be causing this issue? I had it working before even with NLB but after a reboot it just didn't want to come back up. I have been struggling with this for over a week now. I sometimes revert my VM image back to when it was working before NLB was enabled then do it all again but I can't keep doing that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a solution to this issue however deleted the imgage of TMG01 and created a TMG03 box and its all working nice and dandy now.